# wifi hotspot is not working on my motorola droid razr maxx android 4.1 jelly bean

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, wifi-hotspot

I am unable to activate mobile hotspot on my *Motorola Droid Maxx* running Jelly Bean 4.1. When I try to do so it comes up with an error: "you are not subscribed to the service".

What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sign up for this service with your mobile provider (Verizon, TMobile, etc).

Without paying for the ability to use this service, you cannot use it on your device.

There are ways around this (involving Rooting your device, or trying some 3rd party apps) but in standard OS, you can't tether your device without paying your service provider for this capability.